# How to make dropdown select search field to work, when using the Ransack gem on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, search, ransack

I'm using the Ransack gem on Ruby on Rails 4.2.2.

The :name field search works, but I can't get the dropdown select field to work. When I select an item from the dropdown menu and press 'Search', I don't get any search results. This is what I get on the terminal:

```
Started GET "/companies?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bname_cont%5D=&..." for ...
Processing by CompaniesController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"name_cont"=>"", "category_eq"=>"7", "location_eq"=>""}, "commit"=>"Search"}
Company Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies"
Company Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."category" = '7'
Rendered companies/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Completed 200 OK in 217ms
```

Here is my companies_controller.rb

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Company.search(params[:q])
    @companies = @search.result
  end
end
```

Here is the index.html.erb for companies:

```
    <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %> 

       <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :name_cont, 'Company Name' %>
         <%= f.text_field :name_cont, class: 'form-control' %>
       </div>

       <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :category_eq, 'Category' %>
         <%= f.select :category_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, "id", "category", @search.category_eq) %>
       </div>

       <div class="field">
         <%= f.label :location_eq, 'Location' %>
         <%= f.select :location_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, "id", "location", @search.location_eq) %>
       </div>

      <div>  
        <%= f.submit "Search" %>
      </div>

  <% end %>

  <% @companies.each do |company| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= company.name %></td>
    <td><%= company.category %></td>
    <td><%= company.location %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I can't figure out why :name works, but :category and :location don't display anything on search?

Comment: Can you also post the `Company` model?

Comment: I replaced a working ransack select's options with your variables, please try this: `<%= f.select :location_eq, Company.all.pluck(:location, :id) %>`

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, but thanks for the suggestion! I ended up creating the search from scratch with the help of a Railscast tutorial, now it works, but in a totally different way.

Answer (score 0):

<%= f.select :category_eq, options_for_select(Company.all, "id", "category", @search.category_eq) %>